# Android Custom ArrayAdapter Listview is not clickable with Async Task

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter

I have been stuck on this problem for almost a day now and have tried numerous previous posts on Stack Overflow, online tutorials etc. but nothing seems to work in my case. I have tried setting focusable, focusable in touch and clickable to false for all textviews in each row list item, set android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" in the Relative Layout for list_item_main.xml but nothing has worked. Any help will really be appreciated! Thanks The setup is as follows:

tab.xml (Layout for listview):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

list_item_main.xml (Each row item):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/rLayout">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="XYZ"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#808080"
    android:layout_above="@+id/weight"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Qty"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Qty"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Qty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:text="150"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#808080"
    android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="39dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="87dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dateTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:text="Available from: "
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#808080"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Date"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Qty"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text=" 0.000"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:id="@+id/Rate"
    android:textColor="#808080"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Name"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Date"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Date"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="14/08/2007"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:id="@+id/Date"
    android:textColor="#808080"
    android:layout_below="@+id/weight"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dateTitle"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/dateTitle"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text=" Kgs"
    android:id="@+id/weight"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#808080"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Qty"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Name"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Name"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="INR"
    android:id="@+id/currency"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColor="#808080"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Rate"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Rate"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Rate"/>
```

DealAdapter:

```
public class DealAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Offer2SaleTransaction> {

private List<Offer2SaleTransaction> activeDeals;
private Context context;
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DealAdapter.class.getName());


public DealAdapter(List<Offer2SaleTransaction> activeDeals, Context ctx) {
    super(ctx, R.layout.list_item_main, activeDeals);
    this.activeDeals = activeDeals;
    this.context = ctx;
}

public int getCount() {
    if (activeDeals != null)
        return activeDeals.size();
    return 0;
}

public Offer2SaleTransaction getItem(int position) {
    if (activeDeals != null)
        return activeDeals.get(position);
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    if (activeDeals != null)
        return activeDeals.get(position).hashCode();
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_main, null);
    }

    Offer2SaleTransaction deal = activeDeals.get(position);
    TextView textName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Name);
    textName.setText(deal.getName());

    TextView textQty = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Qty);
    textQty.setText(Float.toString(deal.getQty()));

    // Hardcoded date as of now
    TextView textDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Date);
    textDate.setText("01-01-1994");
    logger.info("This is something I want to know " + deal.getSaleDate());

    TextView textPrice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Rate);
    textPrice.setText(Float.toString(deal.getRate()));

    return v;
}

public List<Offer2SaleTransaction> getActiveDeals() {
    return activeDeals;
}

public void setActiveDeals(List<Offer2SaleTransaction> activeDeals) {
    this.activeDeals = activeDeals;
}}
```

Finally, the fragment to display the listview:

```
public class StatusFragment extends ListFragment implements OnItemClickListener{
DealAdapter adpt;
ListView lView;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab, container, false);
    adpt  = new DealAdapter(new ArrayList<Offer2SaleTransaction>(), getActivity());
    lView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    lView.setAdapter(adpt);
    lView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    // Exec async load task
    new EndpointsStatusAsyncTask().execute(new Pair<Context, String>(getActivity(), "XXXXXX"));

    return view;
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "PLEASE WORK",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private class EndpointsStatusAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Pair<Context, String>, Void, List<Offer2SaleTransaction>> {
    private Offer2SaleTransactionApi myApiService = null;
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(EndpointsStatusAsyncTask.class.getName());
    private Context context;
    private String TAG = "Background";

    @Override
    protected List<Offer2SaleTransaction> doInBackground(Pair<Context, String>... params) {
        if(myApiService == null) {  // Only do this once
            Offer2SaleTransactionApi.Builder builder = new Offer2SaleTransactionApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                    .setRootUrl("https:xxxx");

            myApiService = builder.build();
        }

        context = params[0].first;
        String userID = params[0].second;


        try {
            return myApiService.getOffer2SaleTransaction(userID).execute().getItems();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Offer2SaleTransaction> result) {
        if (result == null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "It didn't work", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            logger.info("Failure in connecting to execute onPostExecute");
        }
        else
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            adpt.setActiveDeals(result);
            adpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are extending ListFragment, you have to override `onListItemClick`, and use it in place of `onItemClick`.

- Remove implements OnItemClickListener
- Remove lView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
- Delete onItemClick

Then

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {           
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "PLEASE WORK",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();k(l, v, position, id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works! Feel foolish now as I was looking at the xml files all this while.